# Getting started with Doctrine for Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to get started with Doctrine for Zend. There doesn't seem to be a lot out there to help me with this. I find the website and documentation a bit useless. 
I'm currently looking at [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download) webpage.

There are a few options. I can checkout from subversion or github. Install via PEAR. or download a package.

What should I be doing with the lines of code in the black boxes?
What do I do with a package once I've extracted it?

As an aside
Am I a little out of my depth? Is there anything I should be learning before I start tackling Doctrine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 1.9 and Doctrine Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269850/zend-framework-1-9-and-doctrine-integration)

Comment: @netcoder Yes possibly, this seems to cover some of the topics I'm struggling with. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should have a look at the [Zend Framework webinars](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework), and more specifically the one called [Zend Framework v1 + Doctrine v2](http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/Framework/70170000000bSrG-webinar-zf-v-1-doctrine-v-2-20101214.flv). It's got detailed instructions and links to GitHub where you can download the source presented in the webinar.

The presentation slides can be found at http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Framework-1-+-Doctrine-2.pdf.

Presentation summary :

> Zend Framework (version 1) is an
>   enterprise grade, full stack MVC
>   framework and component library.
>   Doctrine (version 2) is an enterprise
>   grade, ORM (object-relational mapping)
>   framework for PHP 5.3. In this
>   webinar, the ZF and Doctrine teams
>   join forces to demonstrate how best to
>   integrate these two frameworks and
>   produce a ZF powered MVC application
>   where in which the "M" is powered by
>   Doctrine2. Familiarity of PHP 5.3
>   features is suggested.   Presenter – 
>   Ralph Schindler, Jonathan Wage and
>   Guilherme Blanco (87min) Dec 15 2010

You will have to register with Zend though (but that's free, so shouldn't pose any problems I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are some resources you could use to integrate Zend Framework and Doctrine. In example, you could follow this screencasts:

[ZendCasts - Doctrine](http://www.zendcasts.com/category/screencasts/databases/doctrine-databases/page/4/)

I've followed these screencasts, with a few corrections, and I was able to use Doctrine 1.x with Zend Framework applications. You can also view the generated screencasts' code; this option is available in the most of these screen casts.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use Doctrine 2, not version 1.2. The two are not compatible. Here is a presentation that explains why:

http://www.slideshare.net/ralphschindler/zend-framework-1-doctrine-2-6177485

Here are example sources for Zend Framework + Doctrine 2 integration:

https://github.com/fierycode/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

https://github.com/marsbomber/zf1-doctrine2/tree/modular_setup (with modules)

Answer (score 0):

I have already pointed someone in the right direction to integrate Doctrine 1.2 into ZF, my post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180996/how-do-you-work-with-a-relational-database-in-zend-framework/6183354#6183354).

I hope this helps you out.