# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader in D:\localhost\www\zf-blog\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 31

Tags: zend-framework

Today i firstly tryied to integrate Doctrine in Zend following this guide [beberlei](https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine)

my .zf.ini is such:

```
php.include_path = ".;C:\PEAR;D:\localhost\www\ZFDoctrine;D:\localhost\www\ZFDoctrine\library;D:\localhost\www"
basicloader.classes.0 = "ZFDoctrine_Tool_DoctrineProvider"
```

directory with ZFDoctrine is in D:\localhost\www
I think this error is caused by wrong include_path.. Or i even don't know, i'm noob in zend, can someone help me?
P.S. I googled a lot, and people are advising to comment `includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"`
but it don't helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that looks like :

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
```

in your ini file or any other setting of an include path comment it out.

this error occurs often if you are setting include path twice.

Comment: i have not, project is empty :\

Answer (score 0):

I currently use Doctrine 1.2 with ZF with no problems.  I ran through what I did in a previous thread - [How do you work with a relational database in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180996/how-do-you-work-with-a-relational-database-in-zend-framework/6183354#6183354)

I hope this may be of some help to you.

Kind regards

Garry

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the following folder: C:\PEAR.
There might be another copy of the Zend Framework in there which leads you to including it twice.